# How to get the previous or next view

Tags: android, android-view

how can I get the previous view(TextView) of the SlideButton view, and the next view of the SlideButton view.

The SlideButton view with the id "remotelight". I can get the SlideButton view with the method "findViewById".
so after I get the SlideButton View, how can I get the previous view and the next view ,without the help of "findViewById" method.

thanks so much.

below is a part of layout xml:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <com.ivn.SlideButton
        android:id="@+id/remotelight"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `ViewGroup` instance that's acting as a container for your widgets to do this.

See [getChildAt(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) and 
[indexOfChild(View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#indexOfChild%28android.view.View%29)

So `getChildAt(indexOfChild(v)+1)` will get you the next view.

So something like

```
 ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewbyID(R.tableRow1);
 View slideBtn = findViewbyID(R.remoteLight);
 View nextView = container.getChildAt(container.indexOfChild(slideBtn)+1);
```

You should add checks for overflow and that the next view is of the type that you do in fact want.

Comment: thanks so much. however, how can I get the viewGroup instance? Both of the methods are owned by ViewGroup. Thanks again!

Comment: The TableRow object is a ViewGroup. You can get hold of the TableRow with `findViewbyId(R.tableRow1)`

Comment: Hello, are you online, thanks for help me once again! I try my best to wait for your reply.

Comment: en thanks so much haha, and I use "ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)v.getParent();" get the ViewGroup.

Answer (score 0):

I created two functions that put @CjS solution into use:

```
/**
 * @param view
 */
public static View prev(View view) {

    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();

    int indexOfChild = container.indexOfChild(view);

    if ((indexOfChild - 1) >= 0) {

        return container.getChildAt(indexOfChild - 1);

    }

    return null;

}

/**
 * @param view
 */
public static View next(View view) {

    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();

    int indexOfChild = container.indexOfChild(view);

    if (container.getChildCount() > (indexOfChild + 1)) {

        return container.getChildAt(indexOfChild + 1);

    }

    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created an equivalent in Kotlin Extension:

```
fun View.getPreviousView() : View? {
    val container : ViewGroup = this.parent as ViewGroup
    val indexOfChild = container.indexOfChild( this )
    return if (indexOfChild - 1 >= 0) {
        container.getChildAt(indexOfChild - 1)
    } else null
}

fun View.getNextView() : View?{
    val container : ViewGroup = this.parent as ViewGroup
    val indexOfChild = container.indexOfChild( this )
    return if (container.childCount > indexOfChild + 1) {
        container.getChildAt(indexOfChild + 1)
    } else null
}
```